# USB stick extra folders appearing, what is this?

Tags: usb-drive

So on my USB stick I had a problem to where I could not write to it.  I could copy files from it, however I could not change anything on it.  This is not my main question but part of the issue I was having.  A post I read about this earlier allowed the person to write to the drive with root permissions.  However, I could not even do that.  In order to fix this I had to copy all the files off the USB drive then reformat it then copy them back.  Does anyone know why this was going on and how to fix it if it happens again.  Someone said uninstall usbmount and try that?
Anyhow, on to the extra folder part of the USB stick.  Occausionally, a folder will show up on my USB drive that is labeled something like .100 Trash or .1000 Trash something like that.  Anyway, if I open the folder it is full of all the files that I have deleted from my USB stick in the past.  How is this possible and does anyone know what is going on with this?[image: USB Read Only Error]

Comment: Probably failing, replace it ASAP. Do NOT trust anything written to it, make sure you have backups in a known good drive.

Comment: Something other then failing is going on, because it has happened with other USB's